# wifi dongle (ralink 802.11n) is disable

Tags: wifi

in the photo as you see **ralink** (wifi dongle ) is disable and how I can enable.

[image]

`rfkill list all`
`0: phy0: Wireless LAN`
`Soft blocked: no`
`Hard blocked: yes`
`3: phy3: Wireless LAN`
`Soft blocked: no`
`Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Go into System Settings > Network and try from there. If it works, then it's a known bug that happens in some systems..

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work